# How can I use REST API to retrieve role assignment details, including the name of users and service principals from Microsoft purview account?

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-purview

I'm trying to get the role assignments from Microsoft purview using the following REST API:

```
api_endpoint = f"https://{pv_account_name}.purview.azure.com/policystore/metadataroles"
```

With this I am able to obtain the ids, and role name but I am unable to obtain the names of users, service principals, etc. I am writing a python script to get the data, but I have hit a wall. I am unsure how to go about it as this is my first time trying this.

How do I get the role assignments like data curators, collection admins and the name of the users and service principals.

I tried writing a python script like the following code:

```
import requests
import json

# Replace these with your actual values
pv_account_name = "purview"
api_version = "2021-07-01"

# Azure AD credentials
client_id = "b" 
client_secret = "L"
tenant_id = "e"
resource = "https://purview.azure.net"

# Construct the token request URL
token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"

# Set up the token request parameters
token_params = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "resource": resource
}

# Make the token request to get an access token
token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_params)

# Check the token response status
if token_response.status_code == 200:
    token_data = token_response.json()
    access_token = token_data.get("access_token")

    # Construct the API endpoint for role assignments
    api_endpoint = f"https://{pv_account_name}.purview.azure.com/policystore/metadataroles"


    # Set up headers with the access token
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    # Set up parameters for the request
    params = {
        "api-version": api_version,
        # Add any additional parameters as needed
    }

    # Make the GET request to retrieve role assignments
    response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)

    # Check the response status
    if response.status_code == 200:
        role_assignments = response.json()

        # Initialize a list to store role assignments with user or service principal information
        role_assignments_with_names = []

        # Function to retrieve user or service principal information
        def get_user_info(unique_identifier):
            # Make a request to the Azure AD Graph API to retrieve user or service principal info
            user_info_endpoint = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{unique_identifier}"
            user_info_response = requests.get(user_info_endpoint, headers=headers)

            if user_info_response.status_code == 200:
                user_info = user_info_response.json()
                return user_info

        for assignment in role_assignments.get("values", []):
            unique_identifier = assignment.get("principalId")

            if unique_identifier:
                user_info = get_user_info(unique_identifier)

                if user_info:
                    # Combine role assignment and user info
                    role_assignment_with_name = {
                        "role_assignment": assignment,
                        "user_info": user_info,
                    }
                    role_assignments_with_names.append(role_assignment_with_name)

        # Now, role_assignments_with_names contains role assignments with user or service principal info
        print(role_assignments_with_names)

    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

else:
    print(f"Error: {token_response.status_code}")
    print(token_response.text)
```

This return an empty set.

Comment: You can use `GET {Endpoint}/policyStore/metadataPolicies?api-version=2021-07-01-preview` to get the roles and user details too

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the role assignments like data curators, collection admins and the name of the users and service principals.

You need to make below calls to get the name of the users and service principals.

1. I am getting all the roles and Ids of users and service principal assigned to it using below URL.

```
GET https://{purview_name}.purview.azure.com/policyStore/metadataPolicies?api-version=2021-07-01-preview
```

[image]

These two Ids are User Id and Service Principal Id respectively, as I have added a User and a service principal.

[image]

2. To get the names of User and Service principal, I have used

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`.

***Request Body***-

```json
{
    "requests": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/users?$filter=Id eq 'a92f**********e01' or Id eq '3ce***********da1'"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/servicePrincipals?$filter=Id eq 'a92f**********e01' or Id eq '3ce***********da1'"
    }
]
}
```

[image]

**Please note**, while generating token you need to use *`resource : https://purview.azure.net`*  for ***Purview*** and *`resource : https://graph.microsoft.com`* for ***Graph API*** call.